# How to display large numbers that are very close together (in value) in a graph with tight space

Tags: labels, graphs, numbers

Is there a way to write large values ​​where the last digits of the value are the ones that separate them but only use 6 digits, plus the exponent?

I am designing a graph for scientists where the values range is 1.054516E18 +-3. The maximum space in the graph is 6 digits plus the exponent.
If I write them out in plain numbers they are:

10 545 159 999 999 999 997

10 545 159 999 999 999 998

10 545 159 999 999 999 999

10 545 160 000 000 000 000

10 545 160 000 000 000 001

10 545 160 000 000 000 002

10 545 160 000 000 000 003

But since there is only room for 6 digits in the graph this will not work.
If I write them out in scientific e notation they come out like this:

1.0545160000000000089    e19

1.0545160000000000089    e19

1.0545160000000000089    e19

1.054516    e19

1.0545160000000000089    e19

1.0545160000000000089    e19

1.0545160000000000089    e19

But the "interesting" part of the numbers doesn't show. AND they also use too many digits.

Is there a way to write these numbers so the discerning parts of the numbers show with only 6 digits plus exponent? It doesn't have to be scientifically correct. What matters is that the graph is readable.

Comment: You should talk with the scientists, explain your doubts and pain points. They will help you.

Comment: What about *997, *998, *999... and a bottom or top label saying : * = 1.0545160000000000089. Actually, several ideas come to my mind, but they depend on what you use to represent the graphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!